# unpacking a sql select into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Suppose I have a select roughly like this:

```
select instrument, price, date from my_prices;
```

How can I unpack the prices returned into a single dataframe with a series for each instrument and indexed on date?

To be clear: I'm looking for:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: ...
Data columns (total 2 columns):
inst_1    ...
inst_2    ...
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
```

I'm NOT looking for:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: ...
Data columns (total 2 columns):
instrument    ...
price         ...
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
```

...which is easy ;-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Update**: recent pandas have the following functions: `read_sql_table` and `read_sql_query`.

First create a db engine (a connection can also work here):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
# see sqlalchemy docs for how to write this url for your database type:
engine = create_engine('mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')
```

*See [sqlalchemy database urls](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#database-urls).*

#### [pandas_read_sql_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_table.html#pandas.read_sql_table)

```
table_name = 'my_prices'
df = pd.read_sql_table(table_name, engine)
```

#### [pandas_read_sql_query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query)

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT instrument, price, date FROM my_prices;", engine)
```

---

The old answer had referenced read_frame which is has been deprecated  (see the [version history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17156233/revisions) of this question for that answer).

---

It's often makes sense to read first, and *then* perform transformations to your requirements (as these are usually efficient and readable in pandas). In your example, you can [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the result:

```
df.reset_index().pivot('date', 'instrument', 'price')
```

*Note: You could miss out the `reset_index` you don't specify an `index_col` in the `read_frame`.*

Comment: oh like the shortcut. didn't know about this. do you know if this works for psycopg connectors?

Comment: I think it should do, you just set up you connection (`con`) using that, let me know if it does! :)

Comment: +1 for wondering whether this works for you. None of the developers of ``read_frame``/``write_frame`` were regular postgresql users, so we didn't cover it. If you encounter trouble, please [file an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/new).

Comment: Has this been superseded by pandas.io.sql.read_sql? I get an importError when trying to import read_frame in pandas >= 0.18 and the current docs mention read_sql instead.

Comment: @emunsing most definitely. There is also [`read_sql_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_table.html#pandas.read_sql_table) which should be strongly preferred.

Comment: @emunsing updated the answer to reflect that... I should probably delete the old part...

Answer (score 51):

You can pass a cursor object to the DataFrame constructor. For postgres:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db' user='user' host='host' password='pass'")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select instrument, price, date from my_prices")
df = DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns=['instrument', 'price', 'date'])
```

then set index like

```
df.set_index('date', drop=False)
```

or directly:

```
df.index =  df['date']
```

Comment: Did you have a go with `read_frame` and `psycopg`? Any feedback on whether that's working would be much appreciated by the dev team. Thanks!

Comment: # Extract the column names so that columns=columns:           
columns = [elt[0] for elt in cur.description]

Comment: This is the thing I said I was explicitly not looking for, there's no pivot here.

Comment: I retrieve columns dynamically in this way: 
`df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns=[desc[0] for desc in cur.description])`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a better way to fill in the column names than manually typing them in?

Comment: what i have observed with this answer, pandas data frame does not preserve psql datatypes. e.g. all numeric columns into objects. Any help on that.

Comment: How do i make columns automatically according to header index = 0?

Answer (score 19):

> This connect with postgres and pandas with remote postgresql

```
# CONNECT TO POSTGRES USING PANDAS
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas.io.sql as psql
```

> this is used to establish the connection with postgres db

```
connection = pg.connect("host=192.168.0.1 dbname=db user=postgres")
```

> this is used to read the table from postgres db

```
dataframe = psql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM DB.Table", connection)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: This does the thing I explicitly said I did not want in the question.

Comment: Yeah....sure..since i was beginner of python..ll make more explanation over there...

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as sqlio
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("host='{}' port={} dbname='{}' user={} password={}".format(host, port, dbname, username, pwd))
sql = "select count(*) from table;"
dat = sqlio.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
conn = None
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

conn = psycopg2.connect("host='{}' port={} dbname='{}' user={} password={}".format(host, port, dbname, username, pwd))
sql = "select count(*) from table;"
dat = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
conn = None
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(user="",
                            password="",
                            host="",
                            port="",
                            database="")

sql = "select count(*) from table;"
dat = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```