# How to Make SQL Table Show on Pycharm

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a postgres db running on docker. I am able to access this db via my sql client Dbeaver and when I run select statements I see the expected results.

I would like to be able to query this db via a Python script and after some searching found psycopg2 package.

When I run the code below it 'looks' like it's successful, the conn and cursor objects appear as a variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

# connect to db
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="postgres",
    user="postgres",
    password="example")

# create a cursor
cur = conn.cursor()
```

However, when trying to query the db using `cur.connect()`, , variable ex_data is None. This exact same query via my sql client returns a table of data.

```
ex_data = cur.execute('select * from myschema.blah limit 10;')
```

How can I query my db via Python using psycopg2? Desired result wold be a data frame with the result set from the query string above.

Comment: Is the python code located and executed inside the same docker as the db?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unpacking a sql select into a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156084/unpacking-a-sql-select-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Maurice Meyer this has been resolved. Thanks for the help. I followed the guide in this link: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-an-sql-query-result-to-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python

Comment: @snakecharmerb pycharm is not on docker yet. The issue has been resolved though. Thanks